# Installed Webmin on Centos 6.3 VM but cant login with my VM user

Tags: azure

I have just installed a new Linux VM on Azure - Centos 6.3

installed webmin all great

I have then gone ot log in as the user and password I set up for SSH when I created the VM but it wont let me log in, I dont have the root password as it didnt offer me the root option when i installed the VM just the chance to create a user and password

Anybody please advise help?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, Windows Azure doesn't typically give you Administrator or root users. In the case of Linux you start with the azureuser which is setup as a sudo user. So login as the azureuser and 'sudo su'. Now set a root password i.e. passwd root.

Now you should be able to authenticate with webwin.